# Short story: dream machines and androids

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, androids, dreams

A boy sets off on a quest and eventually learns from an oracle/librarian/sentient machine/? that he is an android, and so is everyone in his city, without being aware of it; there are no more real people left. Devastated, he programs his dream-making machine to make himself forget what he had discovered.

I think the author is an Italian.

Comment: Hi, welcomed to SF&F!  Do you recall when you read this?  You should check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for story-id questions to see if they help you recall any additional details you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: Thanks, but it's been more than 25 years, that's about as much as I can remember.